# Script doesn't fully execute in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Hopefully this is something simple. I'm testing a simple Chrome Extension script and it appears it'll execute part of the script, but won't complete it. For example, if I add an `alert()` to the beginning of a script, it will execute the alert. But if I place it after anything calling the `chrome` DOM object, it won't execute. Here's an example:

**Will execute alert**

```
alert("Test");
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function (request) { });
```

**Will not execute alert**

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function (request) { });
alert("Test");
```

Am I missing something?

Here is my manifest:

```
{
  "background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": [
      "scripts/libs/jquery.1.11.2.min.js",
      "scripts/background.js"
    ]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "resources/icon.19.png"
  },
  "icons": {
    "48":  "resources/icon.48.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test",
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "webNavigation",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ],
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing debugging it yourself.

Go to `chrome://extensions/` and load the Dev Tools for your background page. You will see an uncaught exception that stops execution.

For `webRequest` events, you **must** [include a filter argument](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#subscription) to the `addListener` function.